# Caching static files in browser

Tags: python, http, caching, browser, header

I am trying to enable caching for static files such as .css and .js.
I am running a WSGI server with Python.

I have tried setting the following headers for caching purposes:

```
headers.add_header('Cache-control', f'public, max-age={expires.strftime(RFC_1123_DATE)}')
headers.add_header('Expires', expires.strftime(RFC_1123_DATE))
headers.add_header('Last-Modified', generate_last_modified())
```

Headers recieved in the browser:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 08:06:17 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.9
Content-Encodings: 
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
Cache-control: public, max-age=Tue, 28 Apr 2020 08:06:17 GMT
Expires: Tue, 28 Apr 2020 08:06:17 GMT
Content-Length: 23399
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 08:06:1587452777S GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

When using Chrome this code works and the files are stored and retrieved from the cache as you would expect. Chrome is using the **Expires** header and is ignoring the **Cache-Control** header.

I checked my developer tools and **Disable Cache** is not enabled. I checked my settings in Firefox in about:config, caching seems to be enabled.

So what am I missing here? Am I missing a header, is an ETAG required, why is **Expires** working in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Firefox cache was full, so after emptying the cache it started sending the **if-modified-since** header again.

Also my server was returning the current time as the **last-modified** time instead of the actual last modified time.

To fix the issue all I had to do was compare the **if-modified-since** time from the browser with the last modified time from the file and send a 304 status if nothing changed.